# nestjs is always good to use a guard?

Tags: nestjs, guard

I am working on a project using nestjs.

During the project, I was curious about the use of guard.

If I use guard when logging in, I think it is difficult to give feedback on whether the ID is wrong or the password is wrong.
I want to give various messages about possible errors.

So I try to do defensive programming through code without using guard.
Is it okay to not use guard in this situation?
I wonder if it is always good to use guard.

I searched for nestjs that does not use guard, but could not find an answer.

It may be a simple question, but I hope you understand that it is a big concern for me.
Thank you.

Comment: There is no point in using a Guard on the login endpoint. Its one of the few endpoints that should not have any guards so that you can properly execute your login logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use `guards` of course, but these are `helper` functions that make our operations much simpler. The first purpose of the guards is to catch the priority error, if there is a situation where you want to catch an error before that, it is not recommended to use the guard there anyway.The example

```
 @Roles(UserRoles.Admin)
 @UseGuards(AuthGuard("jwt"),RolesGuard)
 async getUser(@Param('userId') userId:string): Promise<Object | User> {   // Return Users by name
    const user = await this.userService.getUserById(userId)
    if(!user) return {msg:"User not found",status:"error"};
    return user 
  }
```

The `first thing` I need to catch before other errors is the user's role and whether she is logged in. We can consider this a `priority`.I then used the errors I needed to catch `inside` the functions. In general, we prefer to use guards if there are some situations where we need to catch them `first.`